# How to pass OData Query Options using requests library in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, odata

Working with an [OData API](https://help.restaurant365.net/support/solutions/articles/12000042523-restaurant365-odata-connector) using Python and Requests library.

Can you pass [System Query Options](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_QueryingCollections) outside of the URL syntax?

```
URL = "https://odata.restaurant365.net/api/v2/views/Transaction?"\
    "$filter=locationId eq xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"\
    " and date eq 2022-01-16T00:00:00Z"\
    " and type eq 'Journal Entry'"

response = requests.get(URL, auth=(USER_NAME, PASS_WORD))
```

How do you pass the Query Option `$filter` in this case:

```
URL = "https://odata.restaurant365.net/api/v2/views/Transaction?"
DATA = {"locationId" : "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "date" : "2022-01-16T00:00:00Z",
    "type" : "'Journal Entry'",
   }
response = requests.get(URL, auth=(USER_NAME, PASS_WORD), params=DATA)
```

Comment: Why can't you add the query to the URL without `params`? You will still need `eq` (or other comparisons) as part of the value. Not clear how you expect `and` to be added to the url, though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the python requests libray but my first impression is that the `?` might not be needed in the `URL` like so:

```
URL = "https://odata.restaurant365.net/api/v2/views/Transaction"
DATA = {"locationId" : "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "date" : "2022-01-16T00:00:00Z",
    "type" : "'Journal Entry'",
   }
response = requests.get(URL, auth=(USER_NAME, PASS_WORD), params=DATA)
```